# Apply rowStyleClass to every row in PrimeReact DataTable

Tags: reactjs, datatable, primereact

I have data and each row/user is formatted something like this:

```
{
  first: <string>
  active: <bool>
}
```

I wish to apply a background color to the entire row if active property is false. Currently I have this, to try to get style applied to every row

```
rowClassName = (rowData) => {
    return {'greyed' : true}; //will be {'greyed': !rowData.active} but this is for demonstration
}

<DataTable value={this.props.users.toJS()} //in render
    selectionMode="single"
    selection={user}
    onSelectionChange={this.props.dispatch.editAccount}
    rowClassName={this.rowClassName}
>
    <Column field="first" header="First" filter={true}/>
</DataTable>

.greyed{ //in css
    background-color: red;
}
```

which is only applying the style to every other row (see picture)
[image: table with zebra stripes]

Any ideas on what I should try? i posted this question on the primeFaces forum 3 days ago and never got a response: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=58605

Comment: Why downvote? i thought I asked the question well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by overriding the css like this

```
.ui-datatable tbody > tr.ui-widget-content.greyed { 
        background-color: #808080;
}
```

Comment: does not work for me, the other answer works

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem while trying out PrimeReact. My issue turned out to be that the default selector that sets the row background was more specific than my own.

This is the default:

```
body .p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

so just having

```
.specialRowColor { background-color: 'blue' }
```

is not specific enough to override the default.  Instead I needed to do this in my css:

```
.p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody .specialRowColor {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: works for me, the actual selected answer here does not